# Semantic action evaluated in grammar constructor (or not?)

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-phoenix

I have been learning boost::spirit and have come across confusion that a semantic action is evaluated during grammar construction. The following code produces the output:

```
string=
```

My assumption is that this output as part of the semantic action attached to the `orule`.

Is there a way to avoid this behaviour? or is it something that I will need to live with if I'm using `std::cout` in a semantic action?

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace phx = boost::phoenix;
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

template <typename Iterator>
    struct my_grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, std::string( )  >
{
    my_grammar() : my_grammar::base_type(orule)
    {
        using qi::_1;
        using qi::_2;
        using qi::attr;
        using qi::string;
        using phx::val;

        orule =  string("abc") [  std::cout << "string=" << _1 << std::endl ];
    }
    qi::rule< Iterator, std::string() > orule;
};

int main()
{
    typedef std::string::const_iterator iterator_type;
    typedef my_grammar<iterator_type> parser;
    parser my_parser; // Our grammar
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No, semantic actions are **not** evaluated during rule initialization.

However, your problem is that you didn't (just) write a semantic action.

---

Yes, in your case the first part of that expression

```
std::cout << "string=" << _1 << std::endl
```

has a side-effect: `(std::cout << "string=")` inserts the literal into the standard ostream object and *then* returns `std::cout` by reference.

This is because you use the `std::operator<<` defined in the standard library, not `boost::phoenix::....::operator<<`¹.

---

You can fix this by *forcing* the type of the second argument to something that will select the right overload:

```
std::cout << phx::val("string=") << _1 << std::endl
```

Of course, you can always make doubly sure by doing e.g.

```
phx::ref(std::cout) << _1 << std::endl
```

But you'll notice that people tend to skip this whenever it's possible. The second operand being `boost::spirit::_1` already *induces expression-template context* (i.e. selects the non-standard operator overloads that construct lazy actors instead of the side-effect).

---

¹ which likely ends up just being `boost::proto::....::operator<<` anyhow, but that's all delicious implementation details :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer - It's given me further insight into what's actually going on in those semantic actions